# I want to register 100k valid Apple IDs

Tags: apple-id

I want to register 100k Apple IDs with 100k different emails automatically. 
I tried using a PHP script but it's not working.
Any ideas on how to achieve this?
I want them to be permanent, and not temporary (for example: Apple ban them in 6 month).

Comment: [This page](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/3948/systematically-creating-250+-apple-id-at-a-time-for-an-organization) at the JAMF user forums may shed some light on why Apple takes steps to minimize the exact thing you're trying to do without pre-authorization. Even _with_ preauthorization, Apple might want to know _why_ you need so many accounts.

Comment: Hah! @IconDaemon you found my post there. Be sure to read to the part where I explain why scripting it is no longer the good plan and the author of the tool mentioned weighs in. Good stuff on that site for sure.

Answer (score 10):

Don't try to register more than 25 accounts in a day is my rule of thumb. Reach out to your Apple sales contact and work with Apple Professional Services or Apple Enterprise Support to create things and make sure you aren't covered with a tool / program to mass enroll or have your user base self-enroll in an efficient manner.

I've had good success getting our needs met across three organizations of differing sizes by reaching out to Apple for this need.

Comment: Did you used any program or script or just make them manually?

Comment: It depends what Apple asks you to do - we never did them manually, that’s for sure. It’s their call how they want you to proceed, though. @MortezaSoltanabadiyan

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have a hard time doing this, even if you got a working script for it. There is no way Apple would allow this from the same IP address before they blacklisted your ip. You're going to need a professional on this one. Just for starters, your going to need to buy a proxy service to keep your accounts on seperate IP's. Furthermore, you will need to do something similar with a paid "Burner" phone service that gives you temporary phone numbers in order to verify an account/accounts. Lastly, your going to need prepaid credit cards for each ID you register, as you cannot use the same payment method for 100k accounts. There are probably many other extra steps you need to take in order to pull something like this off, but I'm not Edward Snowden. Good luck.